# Access has been blocked as the threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website

Tags: php, html, hosting, malware, blocked

The following website is blocked on the school network but only for this student's website. Other students have used the same hosting provider and are on the same network with the same code, as far as we can see, and their sites are not blocked.

The blocked page and site URL is below:

http://minimalstocks.atwebpages.com/login.php

See the image for the error description.

```
Access has been blocked as the threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKkDp.png)

The login script contains very basic PHP code and as mentioned other students have used identical code using the same hosting provider and the code/page works with no errors on the same network.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this error?

Comment: That’s probably a question better directed at whomever is in charge of administrating your “sophos web protection” system there.

Comment: @CBroe - no, because as far as they can see nothing is blocked. As mentioned the exact same scripts and websites with different URLS do work fine.

Comment: _“As mentioned the exact same scripts and websites with different URLS do work fine.”_ - even more of a reason why likely no one here will be able to tell you, why. False positives _happen_. If it is not due to something on your end (configuration of the blocker), then you’d probably have to take the issue to Sophos then.